# A DRYer way to upgrade customer from 1 to 3 to 5 times a week (i.e., Date math!)

Tags: ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

This is one of those things that's super obvious to people, but code wise I'm struggling with how to write it. A customer can be on one of 3 plans:

- Once a week (1) - on Monday, where product is $15 each (or $15 for the week)
- Three times a week (3) - on Wed, Fri, where product is $12 each (or $36 for the week)
- Five times a week (5) - on Mon, Tu, Wed, Th, Fri, where product is $10 each (or $50 for the week)

Upgrade logic is simplified as such:

- If a customer upgrades from 1 to 3, for every Monday already paid for, we now need to add plan_dates for the associated Wed, Fri of that week, and add a Stripe InvoiceItem for $12 * 2 = $24
- If a customer upgrades from 1 to 5, for every Monday already paid for, we now need to add plan_dates for the associated Tu, Wed, Th, Fri of that week, and add a Stripe InvoiceItem for $10 * 4 = $40
- If a customer upgrades from 3 to 5, for every Monday already paid for, we now need to add plan_dates for the associated Th, Fri of that week, and add a Stripe InvoiceItem for $10 * 2 = $20

"every Monday already paid for" is an array `array_of_mondays` in the code. From there, I have a jumbled mess that I can't think about how to DRY up...

```
prices = {1=>15, 3=>12, 5=>10} 
array_of_mondays.each do |m|
  if current_plan == 1 && new_plan == 3
    self.plan_dates.create(ddate: date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(3, 0, m))
    self.plan_dates.create(ddate: date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(5, 0, m))
    Stripe::InvoiceItem.create(
      customer: self.user.stripe_customer_id,
      amount: (new_plan – current_plan) * prices[new_plan],
      currency: “usd”
    )
  elsif current_plan == 1 && new_plan == 5
    self.plan_dates.create(ddate: date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(2, 0, m))
    self.plan_dates.create(ddate: date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(3, 0, m))
    self.plan_dates.create(ddate: date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(4, 0, m))
    self.plan_dates.create(ddate: date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(5, 0, m))
    Stripe::InvoiceItem.create(
      customer: self.user.stripe_customer_id,
      amount: (new_plan – current_plan) * prices[new_plan],
      currency: “usd”
    )
  elsif current_plan == 3 && new_plan == 5
    self.plan_dates.create(ddate: date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(4, 0, m))
    self.plan_dates.create(ddate: date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(5, 0, m))
    Stripe::InvoiceItem.create(
      customer: self.user.stripe_customer_id,
      amount: (new_plan – current_plan) * prices[new_plan],
      currency: “usd”
    )
  end
end
```

The method that I'm using `date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start` helps figure out the actual date:

```
def date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(wday, number_of_days, start_date)
    number_of_days = number_of_days.to_i
    wday = wday.to_i
    day_ahead = start_date + number_of_days.days
    (day_ahead) + ((7 - day_ahead.wday + wday) % 7).days
    #returns Date object
end
```

In other words, what it's doing is it's saying create a `plan_date` with a `ddate` that is the next Tuesday, 0 days out from the specified Monday (e.g., the next Tuesday)

Comment: Do y'all store anything in your own database or are y'all only using Stripe?

Comment: WIth invoices specifically, trying to ONLY use Stripe.

Comment: Why not try using Stripe's subscription and plan objects then? https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#update_subscription

Comment: ah yes sorry i should clarify. the real story is super long, but basically I am using stripe's subscription/ plan objects to update, THIS code is above and beyond the normal update.

Comment: How is it above and beyond? It looks like you're just changing subscription plans.

Comment: When a user upgrades, 2 things happen: 1) the subscription plan gets upgraded (the easy part, all done in Stripe) for your next invoice and beyond, 2) there's an INCREMENTAL adjustment which is the InvoiceItem part that this question is about. The reason is because we offer a discrete service (e.g., not like a gym membership where upon upgrade you immediately can start accessing more. In this case, when you upgrade, we give you more product, but we need time to prepare the product). Does that help? Sorry this is quite hard to explain...

Comment: 1) Sure. Great! 2) I don't follow you. Does the volume of distributed product increase over time to taper out at the subscription tier volume? If so, I'd recommend invoicing for the product be done in a separate operation. Where in you could reference the client's subscription plan to determine how much they owe. Trying to have these changes handled entirely by the subscription plan seems very confusing ( you can't even explain it... ). Additional, your current approaches could have dire consequences when dealing with clients that rapidly change between several different subscription plans.

Comment: #2.. kind of, but that's exactly why this invoicing IS done separately. Hence the InvoiceItem creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok actually I just had a moment of creativity and thought of a possible answer, but would LOVE to hear others:

```
prices = {1=>15, 3=>12, 5=>10}
dates_to_be_created = { [1,3] => [3,5], [1,5] => [2,3,4,5], [3,5] => [4,5] }
array_of_mondays.each do |m|
  dates_to_be_created[[current_plan,new_plan]].each do |d|
    self.plan_dates.create(ddate: date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(d, 0, m))
  end
  Stripe::InvoiceItem.create(
    customer: self.user.stripe_customer_id,
    amount: (new_plan – current_plan) * prices[new_plan],
    currency: “usd”
  )
end
```